# Difference between Location.reload() and window.location.reload()

Tags: javascript

I know this is silly but I really want to understand  Difference between Location.reload() and window.location.reload();

What will happen if I use location.reload() ?
And what will happen if I use window.location.reload();  ?

Answer (score 4):

It is exactly the same, window is an implicit keyword